Invalid login attempt while accessing NetSuite using REST Web Services
I am trying to integrate NetSuite REST Web Services with a Flutter-based application using OAuth 2.0 authentication.
I am using the Administrator role. I have enabled the necessary features, checked all necessary permissions, and set up an integration record. Also using the required parameters in the code including consumer key, consumer secret, redirect Uri, scopes and service configuration.
This my flutter application code
However, when sending the request, Flutter returns the following: Status = Bad Request, StatusCode = 400 {error: "Invalid login attempt"}. In the NetSuite login audit trail, it shows "TokenRejected.
Could someone provide guidance on how to fix this error I'm encountering? I would greatly appreciate any assistance.
Thank you in advance for your help.
I have ensured that my token is correct, active, and intended for the correct integration application. Additionally, I have checked for any extra characters or blank spaces within the tokens I am using.

You should not post code as an image

It's not recommended to use the Administrator role to access the rest service.
REST Web Services Prerequisites and Setup

I would recommend creating a custom role.
Provide that role necessary access records in the permission subtab.

